# TARGIT data reader for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ssis, targit

I am using SQL Server 2016, and Visual studio 2015.

I have an issue with using "TARGIT data reader for Google Analytics".
When I create a data flow task, and trying to move TARGIT component into Dataflow window, i am getting an error (text below)

---

TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.
Could not initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [TARGIT Data Reader for Google Analytics [3]]: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{A7260CEC-4F9E-422E-907B-1EE0671AA7E1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100.get_RuntimeConnectionCollection()
   at TARGIT.SSIS.CustomTasks.DataReaderGoogleAnalytics.Task.ProvideComponentProperties()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProvideComponentProperties(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

---

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{A7260CEC-4F9E-422E-907B-1EE0671AA7E1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Your best bet will be to contact Targit directly.  If you are a customer they offer support.   https://www.targit.com/en/resources/store/datareaderforgoogleanalytics

Comment: I thought that this connector is free, so i didn't buy anything. Am I right?

Comment: That its correct its free but free tends to mean no support.  So if you cant get it working with the default information available chances of getting help are nill. disclaimer: I was the lead developer on this project, I have pinged someone at the company.  But i am not sure if they are still offering any help on this project since i have left the company.

Comment: Anyway it would be great, thanks! I will waiting for answer

Answer (score 1):

I had **exactly** the same behavior.

I've found out, that the reason for this error is, that TARGIT doesn't support SQL Server 2017.
Even if you just have SQL Server 2016 installed, it is possible, that some 2017 components are also installed, with for example Management Studio 2017.
Check if 140 Folder exists in your ProgramFiles\SQl Server.
Somewhere in this folder is a DLL (don't know which one), that is used by SQL Server. Even if you have SQL Server 2016, it always picks the newest version of the DLL by default, and in this case it's one of SQL 2017. I've tried to change that in GAC but wasn't successful. 
You can either try to deinstall everything that has to do with SQL Server 2017 and to hope, that 140 folder is gone after that. If so, SQL Server will pick the DLL in 2016 version and you should be fine. 
Or you can use the old Visual Studio/DSEXEC (of SQL Server 2008R2), which can be installed parallely, to edit and to execute your TARGIT package. That works fine.

Hope that helps.
Cheers
Mr.T